# How to check issues by version instead of build on crashlytics?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

We have lot of builds for each version after we integrated the CI system.
However, if we want to check the issues of one specified version, we have to select all builds of this version, which is very inconvenient.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Hey.. Can you accept my answer if you found it useful? So it may help others. @Feather

Answer (score 3):

You can filter Version on the dashboard.
 Check the image dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to select multiple builds at this time. I'll let the team know you are interested :)